# cauchy sequences and convergence of this sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

we studied that in any metric spaces cauchy sequences are bounded.
and we know that cauchy sequence converges iff it has a convergent subsequence.
when we prove that
$$R$$ is a banach space we had used these two theorem and Bolzano- Weierstrass theroem. that says " Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence."
My question is: as this theroems is valid for any metric space then we can use them to prove that in any metric space cauchy sequences are convergent as we have did in $$ R$$
in fact we know this is not true for example
$$ (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n \subset Q $$ but
$$ (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n \to e\notin Q $$ so it isn't convergent sequence in Q
then my prove is false but I want to know what is wrong with this proof?

Comment: The Bolzano-Weierstraß theorem does not apply to $\mathbb Q\,.$